# Running a script as a different user- why is permission denied?

Tags: bash, permissions, file-permissions

I am running a script as a root that creates a user using `useradd` and `passwd`. Then am doing some checks/installs before running some other commands that need to be run as the newly created user.

So I have the main script that creates the user:

main.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
useradd testuser
passwd testuser

yum -y install git
chmod 777 testuser.sh
su testuser -c ./testuserscript.sh
```

testuserscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone git://github.com/schacon/grit.git
```

When I run ./main.sh: I get the the following error:

```
bash: ./testuserscript.sh: Permission denied
```

When I do ll I get the following:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root  root  728 Jun 24 11:02 testuserscript.sh
```

Am I running the wrong command to run the `testscript` as the `testuser`?

Comment: You could try `sudo -u testuser command`

Comment: Do you have +x on all directories leading up to `testuserscript.sh`?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes. I tried with chmod 777 all the way up to /tmp/. No luck either.

Comment: @thatotherguy both scripts are in /tmp

Comment: Is `/tmp` mounted with noexec?

Comment: is your /tmp a mounted volume, maybe tmpfs, with noexec option?

Comment: I doubt that `noexec` would be the issue. before reaching `testuserscript.sh`, `main.sh` execution would have failed too.

Comment: mount | grep tmp givesm me tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")

Comment: Your su command should look more like "su -c comand user", see https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/su-invocation.html. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied can happen when:

1. The script doesn't have execute permissions for the user which invokes it
2. The path after the hash-bang (`#!`) isn't correct or doesn't point to an executable (or the user doesn't have permissions to execute this script).
3. The user doesn't have execute permission for all the folders leading to the script.

In your code, you're setting chmod 777 to `testuser.sh` but then you try to execute `testuserscript.sh`

I don't expect `su` to change the folder but maybe try absolute paths. Also check the default shell of the newly created used. To circumvent all this (and a couple of other problems), try:

```
sudo -u testuser bash /tmp/testuserscript.sh
```

You can later use variables to define in which folder all the scripts are.